# Proving a function is continuous and differentiable at $0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

The question I have been asked is:

> **Let $f$ be the function defined by**:
>
> $f(x)=\begin{cases}\
>         e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x>0\\
>         0 & x \leq 0\\
>       \end{cases}$
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous at 0 and differentiable at $0$, and also compute the
>   derivative $f '(0)$. (Hint: you may use, without proof, the fact that $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^n}\to 0$
>   as $x → 0$ for any $n ∈ \Bbb{N}$.)

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. I have a solution but it is very poorly worded, looking for a simpler and more understandable explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume that $\exp(a)$ is continuous?

Comment: That's not been stated, so no I don think so in this case.

Comment: oh, I didn't saw what you can assume from the hint

Comment: @JonnyWhite13 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x\to0$, $\frac1x\to\infty$, hence $e^{-\frac1x}\to0$. So $f$ is continuous at $0$.
Moreover by L'Hospital's rule $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-\frac1h}-0}h=\lim_{h\to0}e^{-\frac1h}\frac1{h^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}x^2=0$$
So $f'(0)$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

compute the term $$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ and then compute the Limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ if this Limit exists

Comment: in this instance what is 'h'?

Comment: a variable not a constant

Comment: So, as f approaches 0 from the left h is always 0, by the definition.

Comment: And as f approaches 0 from the right its limit is also 0, so, as the limits agree it is differentiable?

Comment: but the question is for $x=0$

Comment: both Limits from the right and left must be the same

Answer (score 1):

For the continuity you should verify that:

$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=f(x_0)$$

For the derivability that the following limits exist and are equals

$$\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

Note: derivability $\implies$ continuity.

Comment: What does your note mean? I'm a little confused, sorry.

Comment: @JonnyWhite13 if you show that f is derivable it implies that f is also continuos, hence if the 2 limits exists you are done. Otherwise in generl you might have functions non derivable but continuos, in these cases you can verify continuity by the first limit (eg f(x)=|x|).

Comment: Gimusi. Allow a Bravo!! You mention right and left limits!! Most of the above colleagues check only one side.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}=\lim_{t \to +\infty}te^{-t}=0$$

Where we do the change of variables: $$t=\frac{1}{x} \to +\infty  \text{  as   } x \to 0^+$$

Also $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{0}{x}=0$

So both side limits exist at zero and are equal to zero thus $f$ is differentiable at zero  thus continuous at zero and $f'(0)=0$

With  a bit more work you can show that this function is infinitely differentiable at every point.

Comment: Mariios. Possibly too pedantic. You nicely show that the right hand limit exists. The left hand limit is zero. Left hand limit = Right hand limit , hence differentiable at 0. As you know, y=|x| , right hand limit exists.Would  a mention of the (trivial) left hand limit be in place?

Comment: @PeterSzilas i thought it would be obvious that the left hand side limit is zero..but why not..?? i will edit my answer..thanks!

Comment: Mario's. It is , just put in a word or two, looks nicer, I feel. Nice answer. +1

Comment: @PeterSzilas i edited..now i think it is complete :)

Comment: Marios. Very nice! :))